# trouble retrieving an email from an username from a text document

Tags: python, bottle

so I have this website that allows me to get the email from a user that has signed up to the website, so when you sign up it adds your discord username and your email after it in a text file like this

```
Discorduser#0182 Test@example.com
Discordusernumber_one#0182 Testboi@example.co.uk
```

However, it retrieves the email from the first line when i put in the first option, but if i do the 2nd user, it cant seem to find it, here is the code to the website... the code is part of a bottle.py script but here is the main parts of this page

```css
@get('/get_confirm')
def confirm():
    return CONFIRM_PAGE

@post('/get_confirm')
def confirm():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    for line in open('Confirmations.txt', 'r').readlines():
        login_info = line.replace('\n', '').split()
        if name == login_info[0]:
            return CONFIRM_PAGE.replace('''<h1 id='emailbox'></h1>''', '<h1>' + login_info[1] + '</h1>')
        else:
            return CONFIRM_PAGE.replace('''<h1 id='emailbox'></h1>''', '<h1>' + 'That user is not valid' + '</h1>')
```

```html
CONFIRM_PAGE = '''
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/icon.ico">
    <title>TylerR - get_confirms</title>
    <style>
        .content {
  background: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}    

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style='background-size: cover; background-image: url(\"/static/WebisteBackground.png\"); background-attachment: fixed;'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='/commands'>Commands</a></li>
        <li><a href='/youtube'>Youtube</a></li>
        <li><a href='/downloads'>Downloads</a></li>
        <a href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTHnGh3DpDXMyuL03ove1tQ'>
            <img align='right' src='/static/youtubelogo.png' style="width:40px;height:40px;">
        </a>
        <a href='https://www.instagram.com/drumsnaps/'>
            <img align='right' src='/static/Insta.png' style="width:40px;height:40px;">
        </a>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <center>
    <h1 style="font-family:Cooper Black; font-size: 7em;"><b>Confirmations<b></h1>
    <br>
    <h1>Please enter an username to retrieve email</h1>
    <h3>When entering name, replace any spaces with _</h3>
    <form method='POST'  action='/get_confirm'>
        <h2>Discord Username:</h2>
        <input name='name' type='text' placeholder='User#0000'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit'>
        </form>
        <div class='content'>
            <h1 id='emailbox'></h1>
        </div>
  </center>
  </body>
  </html>
  '''
```

I am using bottle.py

so if anyone could let me know why this is happening that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your check it returns immediately - with success (if user is on the first line) or no success (if user is not on first line). You want to return no success, only after you checked all lines.

```
@post('/get_confirm')
def confirm():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    with open('Confirmations.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            user, email = line.strip().split()
            if name == user:
                return CONFIRM_PAGE.replace('''<h1 id='emailbox'></h1>''', '<h1>' + email + '</h1>')

     return CONFIRM_PAGE.replace('''<h1 id='emailbox'></h1>''', '<h1>' + 'That user is not valid' + '</h1>')
```

Also, better use template engine like jinja2 to construct the HTML page.

Comment: it now gives me this error

https://imgur.com/fvpnX1z

Comment: Check your indentation, you didn't dedent the last line correctly. It should be outside the loop and aligned with the first 2 lines of the body of the function.

Comment: its all indented as you can see in this image https://imgur.com/4ickRec

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted your corrected code

Comment: No, you didn't literally copied and pasted my code. I use 4 spaces per level for indentation. In your code (the image) you have mix of 1-, 2-, 3- spaces per level. Correct your indentation. Also I don't see if there is code after the last line you show in the image and what indentation it has.

Comment: thankyou, it worked now, I had to delete the space and redo them, IDK what happened, but I counted the spaces before I redid it and it was 4 spaces, but thankyou because it now works